# Using column data from another table for the where clause of two joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I basically have three tables, trans, master, and period. I wanted to display data from trans and master, but use the data from period for the where clause.

This is my current query, though it returned an error 1064 from on the third line:

```
SELECT b.projname AS companies,SUM(otreg_h) AS hours, SUM(otreg_m) AS minutes FROM trans AS a
JOIN MASTER AS b ON a.empno = b.empno
WHERE otreg_h != 0 AND otreg_m != 0 AND pdate BETWEEN STRDate IN(SELECT STRDate FROM period) AND ENDDate IN (SELECT ENDDate FROM period)
GROUP BY b.projname
ORDER BY SUM(otreg_h) DESC LIMIT 15
```

What did I do wrong here?

EDIT: This is the current structure of table 'period'

```
PayCat - varchar(1) NOT NULL
PayMonth - int(10) NULL
PeriodNo - int(10) NULL
(Foreign key)STRDate - date NOT NULL
(Foreign key)ENDDate - date NOT NULL
PAYDate - date NULL
Processed - tinyint(3) NOT NULL
Posted - tinyint(3) NOT NULL
Pyear - varchar(50) NULL
id - bigint(10) NOT NULL
date1 - date NULL
date2 - date NULL
```

Comment: The use of the 'period' table is probably wrong, right now you're selecting all rows from that table when reading start date and end date. This will only work if there is only one row in that table otherwise you need to join it with the 'trans' or 'master' table on some id like 'empno' or a project identifier so that you only get one row back.

Comment: Could you share the structure of the period table please.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: My apologies, I've edited the main question to show the structure of table period.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see the connection between 'period' and 'trans' and/or 'master'. I understand you want your query to be run for a given date range (STRDate to ENDDate) but I don't understand how this range is selected.

Comment: I was kind of hoping I could select all the data from STRDate and ENDDate for the where clause, so that it will display all possible data from the sets of date range. But it looks like I might have to just run each dual field separately by queries..

Comment: You could if there is a link (foreign key) between 'period' and 'trans' or between 'period' or 'master' that could be used but I can't see anyone.

Comment: I think you need to include the structure for trans and master also or explain the link to period that I have asked about.

Comment: There is a datetime field on table 'trans' called 'pdate', which I'm using as a guide for STRDate and ENDDate. If pdate falls in between table 'period's STRDate and ENDDate, then the query should pull the selected data from that. (trans table is also quite long, so I'm not sure if I should define it entirely.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little hesitant to supply an answer here since I am not sure there is a correct answer but given the comment that the pdate should be between STRDate and ENDDate from period and nothing else then the following comparison would do

```
 pdate BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(STRDate) FROM period) AND (SELECT MAX(ENDDate) FROM period)
```

So the full query would then be

```
SELECT b.projname as companies, sum(otreg_h) as hours, sum(otreg_m) as minutes 
FROM trans a
JOIN master b on a.empno=b.empno
WHERE otreg_h != 0 AND otreg_m != 0
AND pdate BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(STRDate) FROM period) AND (SELECT MAX(ENDDate) FROM period)
GROUP BY b.projname
ORDER BY hours DESC LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score -1):

You have used strdate 2 times

```
SELECT
  b.projname AS companies,
  SUM(otreg_h) AS hours,
  SUM(otreg_m) AS minutes
FROM
  trans AS a
  JOIN MASTER AS b ON a.empno = b.empno
WHERE
  otreg_h != 0
  AND otreg_m != 0
  AND pdate BETWEEN (
    SELECT
      STRDate
    FROM
      period
  )
  AND ENDDate IN (
    SELECT
      ENDDate
    FROM
      period
  )
GROUP BY
  b.projname
ORDER BY
  SUM(otreg_h) DESC
LIMIT
  15
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT b.projname AS companies,SUM(otreg_h) AS hours, SUM(otreg_m) AS minutes FROM trans AS a
JOIN MASTER AS b ON a.empno = b.empno
WHERE otreg_h != 0 AND otreg_m != 0 AND pdate BETWEEN (STRDate IN(SELECT STRDate FROM period)) AND (ENDDate IN (SELECT ENDDate FROM period))
GROUP BY b.projname
ORDER BY SUM(otreg_h) DESC LIMIT 15